# Android - How to set color of a TextView and background together with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, background-color

in my app I have a menu button called "Settings" in which I can choose what colours set up to the background of some layout. Unfortunately I combine two layouts together to show what I want to show, and the problem is that I can only set background colour (that is in a layout) but not the the colour of TextView (that is in the other layout).

Layout main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/main_layout">
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/editText1" 
android:layout_height="65dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
android:hint="Scrivi" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout listitem_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/main_layout">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</TextView>
<TextView
android:text="TextView"
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class SearchCocktail extends Activity{
EditText ed;
ListView lview; 

String[] first = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",     "Nine", "Ten"};

String[] second = { "Uno", "Due", "Tre", "Quattro", "Cinque", "Sei", "Sette", "Otto",  "Nove", "Dieci"};

int textlength = 0;
ArrayList<String> first_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> second_sort = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(first, second));
...........
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View row;

row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, parent, false);

TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

textview.setText(data_first[position]);
textview1.setText(data_second[position]);

return (row);
}
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();

String colorePref = prefs.getString(PreferencesFromXml.COLORE_PREF,  PreferencesFromXml.COLORE_DEFAULT);
int coloreDiSfondo = Color.parseColor(colorePref);
findViewById(R.id.list).setBackgroundColor(coloreDiSfondo);
editor.commit();    
}
}
```

PreferencesFromXml activity:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class PreferencesFromXml extends PreferenceActivity{

public static final String COLORE_DEFAULT = "#000000";

public static final String COLORE_PREF = "colore";

public static final String TITOLO_PREF = "titolo";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    Preference titoloPrefs = findPreference(TITOLO_PREF);
    titoloPrefs.setSummary(prefs.getString(TITOLO_PREF, getString(R.string.titolo_custom)));
    titoloPrefs.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener()
    {
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference prefs, Object value)
        {
            prefs.setSummary((CharSequence) value);
            return true;
        }
    });editor.commit();
}
}
```

With my code I can change background colour of layout main.xml but I want change also the TextView colour of listitem_row.xml. I'd like to change the colours together (example: black colour for background and white colour for the text or white colour for the background and black colour for the text, etc.). How can I proceed? Thanks to everyone who can answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understood PreferenceActivity, PreferenceManager, or your question when I first answered.  Your problem is with styling your list, not with storing your preferences, right?

I think setting a theme on the activity might be a solution.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580424/931277) talks about how to update text colors when the theme is changed. [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) is probably the place to start reading about themes.